# Setting the value of handsonTable control element using capybara

Tags: capybara, html-table, handsontable

```ruby
@integration @no-database-cleaner @javascript
  Scenario: Create New Mortality Table for ShipCase 2.2.2.5
    Given shipcase user logs into test environment with password: "*******"
    Given the user chooses to add a new mortality base table
    And the user specifies "TestScriptMortalityTable" as name for base mortality table
    And the user chooses "Male" as Gender , "qx" as type, "United States" as region and "2011" as base year for the mortality table
    And I specify the following mortality rates:
      | age   | mortality_risk |
      |  0  |  0.1  |
      |  1  |  0.2 |
      |  2  |  0.000200332  |
      |  3  |  0.000200332  |
      |  4  |  0.000200332  |
      |  5  |  0.000200332  |
      |  6  |  0.000200332  |
      |  7  |  0.000200332  |
      |  8  |  0.000200332  |
      |  9  |  0.000200332  |
      |  10  |  0.000200332  |
      |  11  |  0.000200332  |
      |  12  |  0.000200332  |
      |  13  |  0.000200332  |
      |  14  |  0.000200332  |
      |  15  |  0.000200332  |
      |  16  |  0.000200332  |
      |  17  |  0.000200332  |
      |  18  |  0.000200332  |
      |  19  |  0.000200332  |
      |  20  |  0.000200332  |
    #And I save the profile
```

I am able to get the value in the value variable, but cannot set it. I still get a 0 when I explicitly set the value. Can anyone suggest why? I just figured out that the table is rendered using JavaScript and it uses HandsOnTable control. The control has a text area with specific CSS. I am using code above to set it. ITs a text area. But still capybara says the element is not found.
I see the click happening on the `<td>`. but I cannot set text , capybara complains that it cannot find the text area.

Steps file is below

```ruby
Given /^I specify the following mortality rates:$/ do |mortality_table|
  @mortality_data = mortality_table.hashes        
  @mortality_data.each_with_index do |data, i|
    row = first(:xpath, "//div[@id='mortality-table-data']//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'#{data["age"]}')]/..")
    row.find(:xpath,"td[2]").click
    sleep 3
    elem = page.driver.find_element(:css, 'handsontableInput')
    puts elem.object_id
  end
end
```

When I do the page source I see the element

```html
<div class="handsontableInputHolder htHidden" style="top: 91px; left: 58px; overflow: hidden;"><textarea class="handsontableInput" style="height: 0px; width: 0px;"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: Better show your test. (Hoping it has js: true or @javascript as appropriate.)

Comment: I added both the feature and step definition